# How did ancient civilizations obtain the information to create the star map?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

The star map found in all those ancient civilizations pointing to the Engineer outpost - do we know anything about how the ancients obtained the information needed to create the star map?  It has to have been relayed fairly concurrently with when the paintings/carvings were done, since stars change position quickly (at least when you think in time scales spanning back to the engineer pan-sperming earth hundreds of millions of years ago)...

Comment: Just how quickly do you think stars change positions? Moving a thousand kilometers per hour is nothing when the distances are in the hundreds of light-years.

Comment: @aslum - just clarified that -- i guess what i mean is that the the clues to the star positions can't have been left at the same time as the original engineer disintegrated himself at the start of the movie -- that would have been far too early to predict the positions of those stars by the time that civilized humanoids evolved.. so, I mean quickly in a geologic/galactic time scale

Comment: @aslum You're right, but further evidence of them being recent is that the map reflects continental drift on Earth.

Answer (score 6):

All of the Earth civilizations who were privy to the Engineer's star system maps would have been given that information, **by the Engineers** in the worst case scenario, 30,000 years ago. In stellar terms, those stars would have barely moved at all in relationship to the Earth. And seeing that they are created as ART, there would have been obvious differences that would be compensated for using technology once the right stars were found.

There is, of course, some stellar drift on their part and ours, but 30,000 years is insignificant on a galactic scale for those stars to have drifted beyond our ability to identify them, particularly in relationship to each other.

Stellar movement is incredibly slow given the distances between stars; it takes an estimated 215-250 million years for the galaxy to rotate just once.

Comment: the engineers seem to be depicted in the paintings/carvings with the stars - so it is possible that they visited the ancient civilisations at some point